# Selenium webdriver stalling after timeout

Tags: python, selenium, timeout, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium webdriver on chrome to scrape a website's search results, with python 3.6 on Windows 10. When using driver.get(), certain pages do not load, and selenium times out (regardless of how long I set the timeout for). My error is that after timing out, I cannot get another url. My code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
for link in link_list:
    try:
        driver.get(link)
        # do some stuff
    except:
        continue
```

What happens is that if `driver.get(somelink)` throws a timeout exception, then `driver.get` will fail every subsequent time. The chrome window itself stalls on `somelink` permanently.
It seems like `driver` is stopping completely if it throws an exception, regardless of whether or not I catch it. I am not sure if this happens regardless of the *type* of exception, or if it only happens on timeout. I have a workaround where I close and re-open the window, but it's messy. Is there any way to make the browser continue?

Comment: I'm having the same behaviour using a comparable setup. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Seems to be a long-standing bug in Selenium that has no solution currently. I will attempt to develop some sort of workaround.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long-standing bug in Selenium and has no solution currently.